# Css coding style - selector nesting

Tags: html, css, coding-style

I'm vastly trying to build a solid and responsive coding style. My general question concerns styling child classes. Let me give example first:

```
    <div class="pageHeader">
        <div class="cnt">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#" title="logo">My Logo</a>
            </div> <!-- .logo-->
            <div class="menu">
            </div> <!-- .menu-->
        </div> <!-- .cnt-->
    </div><!-- .pageHeader -->
```

I use the pageContainer / pageHeader/ pageBody / pageFooter notation for my main page structure. So here's the question: How should i write specific selector like .logo ? Which notation should i use and why:

```
.pageHeader .cnt .logo a {}
.pageHeader .logo a {}
.cnt logo a{}
.logo a{}
```

Obviously if you you have better idea for notation in this case, please tell.

Comment: Your `.cnt` class is reluctant. You usually never need a double wrapper (it has no siblings...)

Comment: Do you mean .cnt class? Well im using pageHeader in this case for 100% width, than .cnt for centering the content in 960px (with background color for whole width). Unless your talking about other part, please do explain

Comment: Why not use the body as your 100% and `.pageHeader` as the centering 960px wide div? Also, in HTML5, there's the `<header>` element exactly for headers.

Comment: Well this is valid point but in case when i want to have background across the element for 100% width, and then content within 960, than this solution is more safe and futureproof (in case you suggest adding background image that would fill the top of page). Thanks for conercn tho.

Comment: You are correct. That's why I said "usually", there are some very specific cases when you do need one. Just making sure you're not making a silly mistake. Carry on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 2

```
.pageHeader .logo a {}
```

The reason is that I want to not have to worry about reusing generic class names elsewhere in the app, so I want to scope everything by it's "component" container. On the other hand, I don't want to default to the max level of specificity, which is why I don't do line 1

Answer (score 1):

In the particular example you provide, it's better to use the `#logo` and `#logoHref` id selectors, since they are going to be unique across the page. Also, it is better to use the child selectors whenever possible (`.pageHeader > .cnt > .logo`), since browsers evaluate selectors right-to-left, so it is better to cut off the DOM traversal early on. This, however, is perfectly justified only for huge pages with lots of elements/rules.

Comment: Do you mean that child selector is faster than descendant? (some old article poped out in my head that said to not use child selector if it's not necessary, that's why i ask)

Comment: Things are changing rapidly in the browser engines, and generally, things should work fast both ways, but with `.a .b` the browser will traverse the entire DOM up to the HTML to find an `.a` element, while with `.a > .b` it will stop on the immediate parent that is not `.a`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the shortest possible CSS selector that you can that is specific enough to select just what you want, but not so vague that it could potentially select others.

CSS selectors are read right-to-left, which means .pageHeader .logo would find .logo, then read up the DOM to find make sure an instance of .pageHeader is a parent, thus selecting that .logo element. But if you were to use .pageHeader .cnt .logo, it would find all .logo then make sure that .cnt is a parent, then check for .pageHeader. The .cnt check is unecessary (this depends on your markup in general, but hopefully you get the idea)

Better yet, give your logo an id (#logo) and just select it using #logo. IDs are more performant, followed by classes, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your intent right, I think [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is what will serve you better.

Comment: There's no better or worse in computer science, programming, web design. There's more or less suited, depending on circumstances and developer skills. Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In first place in html5 exist web semantic you can use tag  , ,  , is better use this instead of class or id pageHeader, pageFooter, etc.

The first, third and four option works well.

I recommended change class="logo" for id="logo" and use:

```
#logo a {}
```

Because the logo sure is unique in all html code.

Comment: The logo is just example content, altho Matt's answer makes more sense there. I want to write clean code that explains the structure well, without pointless selector nesting. I'm also not sure how html5 tags work in older browsers.